# Get product names for a large number of SKUs

Tags: product

I have been given a list of about 150 SKUs in a CSV and I need to get their product names.

I currently have the following code:

```
 require_once('app/Mage.php');
 Mage::app();

 $csv = file('Product - Sheet1.csv');
 $data= array();
 foreach($csv as $line){
     $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
 }

 $products= array();
 foreach($data as $k => $entry){
     if ($k < 1) continue; // First row contains the CSV headers
     $products[$k]['sku'] = $entry[0];
     $model == Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$entry[0]);
     $products[$k]['title']= $model->getName();
 }
```

If I do

```
 print_r($products)
```

I get a blank page, presumably because I'm loading the catalog/product model in the foreach loop.

How do I achieve the same solution but without overloading the system? I know loading models in a foreach is bad practice but I thought I could get by because its not on a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do one thing.read the csv and try to load all your 150 product skus in an array and use the following code to get the product names

```
$productSku = array('sku1','sku2');
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $productSku));
$productNames = $productModel->getColumnValues('name');
print_r($productNames);
```